# How to unzip tar.Z file through CHEF cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using a Chef hosted server, a workstation and nodes and have run cookbooks on the nodes to install Java, update hosts file. I'm not able to find a reference in sites to unzip tar files. Could you please help me out here or direct to some site which has the information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's actually nothing built into Chef for doing extracting a tar file. You have two options, either you can use the [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) resource to shell out and untar or use some community cookbook like the [tar cookbook](https://github.com/gofullstack/tar-cookbook) that have [custom resources defined for extracting tars](https://github.com/gofullstack/tar-cookbook#resourcesproviders).

In the `execute` resource example it might look something like

```
execute 'extract_some_tar' do
  command 'tar xzvf somefile.tar.gz'
  cwd '/directory/of/tar/here'
  not_if { File.exists?("/file/contained/in/tar/here") }
end
```

Whereas the third party tar cookbook definitely [reads nicer](https://github.com/gofullstack/tar-cookbook#example)

```
tar_package 'http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/1446/pgpool-3.4.1.tar.gz' do
  prefix '/usr/local'
  creates '/usr/local/bin/pgpool'
end
```

Comment: The tar cookbook isn't actively under development any more. And I cannot get it to work with local extraction so the variant with execution of the tar command was working for me. There are alternative cookbooks (like [tarball-chef-cookbook](https://github.com/ooyala/tarball-chef-cookbook) but that isn't part of the supermarket and does not support custom tar parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Since Chef Client 15.0 there is a [`archive_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) resource built-in. It supports tar, gzip, bzip, and zip.

```rb
archive_file 'Precompiled.zip' do
  path '/tmp/Precompiled.zip'
  destination '/srv/files'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the package 'tar' needs to be installed and then we can use chef's execute resource to run the tar command. You could use the following snippet.

```
package 'tar'
execute "extract tar" do
 command 'tar -xf #{tarPath} -C #{installPath}'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below chef resource works absolutely fine

```
execute "Extract tar file" do
  command "tar -xzvf #{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/temp.tgz -C #{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/temp"
  action :run
end
```

'temp.tgz' archive file will get extracted into 'temp' dir

path for '#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}' would be like /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/ on linux distributions.